# low dropout regulator output voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, analog, ldo

I want to use the DMOS low-Dropout regulator REG102 3V3, but in the datahseet [REG102](http://datasheetz.com/data/Integrated%20Circuits%20%28ICs%29/Voltage%20Regulators%20-%20Linear/REG102GA-AG4-datasheetz.html) of the regulator i found two configuratons. The first configuration is without resistors divider and by connecting a capacitor on the output. The second configuration is with voltage divider,in this configuration the voltage Vout is depending on the values of the resistors and voltage Vref as is shown in the figure below:
[image: REG102 with resistors]
My question is :
How the voltage Vin influence the voltage Vout in case of use of the voltage divider ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's described on the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/reg102-25.pdf) here:

[image]

For Vout, use the voltage from the table you've quoted (which depends on the resistors).

As you can see, the output voltage changes only slightly with input voltage until you closely (say within 0.25V or so, depending on output current) approach the dropout voltage. For voltages less than the dropout voltage it will tend to follow the input voltage down. No information is given as to what happens at very low input voltages.